# creating elements with namespace prefix based on multipart xml root declaration

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces, prefix

If I do something like this:

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
XmlElement e = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ShipmentReceiptNotification");
e.SetAttribute("xmlns", "urn:rosettanet:specification:interchange:ShipmentReceiptNotification:xsd:schema:02.02");
e.SetAttribute("xmlns:ssdh", "urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:AccountClassification:xsd:codelist:01.03");
XmlNode ShipmentReceiptNotification0Node = e;

ShipmentReceiptNotification0Node.InnerText = String.Empty;
xmlDoc.AppendChild(ShipmentReceiptNotification0Node);
XmlNode DocumentHeader1Node = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ssdh:DocumentHeader");
ShipmentReceiptNotification0Node.AppendChild(DocumentHeader1Node);
```

It will result in the prefix of the second node `ssdh` not to display, only `DocumentHeader` is displayed. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create it like this:

```
XmlNode DocumentHeader1Node = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ssdh", "DocumentHeader", "urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:AccountClassification:xsd:codelist:01.03");
```

The point is `XmlDocument` needs to know which namespace prefix (first argument) corresponds which namespace URI (third argument). A little bit counter-intuitive, but this is the way it works.

Also note that the line `ShipmentReceiptNotification0Node.InnerText = String.Empty;` is useless; it's safe to omit it, the element is empty *by default*.

Comment: so everytime I have a ssdh I need to declare the namespace again by element?

Comment: Yes. Declaring a constant and a helper method is a good idea…

Comment: also it results in  <ssdh:DocumentHeader xmlns:ssdh="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:AccountClassification:xsd:codelist:01.03">  I would prefer just <ssdh:DocumentHeader>

Comment: Did you check it *after* adding into the `xmlDoc`? When I take your code fragment and replace *just the one line with the respective `CreateElement` it works as expected (=no duplicate `xmlns:ssdh` in the nested element).